# Correct args for cv::Mat::split(args)

Tags: c++, opencv, c++14, opencv3.0

I need to  use the function split() which has the signature :

```
void split(const Mat& src, Mat* mvbegin)
```

I came across this signature through the  [official documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20split(const%20Mat&%20src,%20Mat*%20mvbegin)).
I tried the following:

```
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<array>
#include<vector>

using namespace std; 
using namespace cv; 

int main(){

    //Common Parts : 
    //Loading the image : 
    Mat modified1 = imread("sample.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    /* ATTEMPT 1 : This works : 
    *********************/
    vector<cv::Mat> rgb ;
    cv::split(modified1 , rgb); 

    /********************/

    /* ATTEMPT 2 : Does not work
    ********************/
    Mat* rgb1{nullptr} ;
    //rgb1 = &modified1;  Doesn't make a difference.
    cv::split(modified1 , rgb1); 
    /********************/

    return 0 ; 
}
```

The `Attempt 1` works and this  is what i have seen people doing while searching for answers on stackoverflow. 
The error i get for `Attempt2`  is : `segmentation fault (core dumped)`

My questions is  :
1.)Why does not `Attempt2` work ,when i am following the function signatures  ?

2.)Why does  `Attempt1` work ?

Comment: You are expected to provide a prepared array of empty Mat objects. `split()` will not allocate the array for you.

Comment: Thanks , but it was not explicitly written in the document .

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the overloaded function as the below:

```
Mat rgb1[3] ;
cv::split(modified1 , rgb1);
```

For extra information that why we should use the function like this you can take a look at the documentation via this [link](https://docs.rs/opencv/0.21.2/opencv/core/fn.split.html), specially the below one:

> mvbegin: output array; the number of arrays must match src.channels(); the arrays themselves are reallocated, if needed.

So it says that you should define an array with size 3(or src.channels).

Answer (score 0):

So i have figured out the way to do it , thanks to @[ypnos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21974/ypnos).

1.) It has to be remembered that if an `array` in `C++` is initialized as :

```
int arr1[3] ={31,21,57};
cout<<*arr1<<endl //Prints 31
```

Meaning the array points to the first element stored in the array . This does not hold with `std::array` though.

So building on the same understanding,we can initialize and then split the array as :

```
  Mat rgb1[3]  ;
cv::split(modified1 , rgb1);
```

So that `rgb1` behaves like a pointer of the type `Mat` and satifies the signature of

```
void split(const Mat& src, Mat* mvbegin)
```

But the fact that `mvbegin` has to be an array of size 3 not just  pointer object is something i did not find *explicitly* written in the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20split(const%20Mat&%20src,%20Mat*%20mvbegin))  .